# WAMP include_path errors

Tags: php, wamp, pear, include-path

I am picking up on a project finished by a colleague but needs improvement. I installed a WAMP server on windows PC and most of the integration on my server is working fine except for the fact that I can not get past this error :

```
Warning: require_once(DB.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\includes\includes.inc.php on line 40

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\includes\includes.inc.php on line 40
```

First off I do not have a C:\php\pear folder the pear folder is located in

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear
```

I have stopped my services in WAMP and then went to the php.ini and change these settings :

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear"
```

I checked his .htaccess file for anything that could possibly be overriding my include path and nothing.

The only place that I have seen in his project that he has a include_path set is :

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/capeadmin/includes");
```

I can't seem to put my finger on this.

Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: your problem looks like it might be stemming from your `DB.php` file. Mask your user / pass / host, and give us that code so we can have a look.  It looks like you are trying to include "../includes/includes.inc.php" when you really mean "includes/includes.inc.php" ?

Comment: I don't have DB.php even configured yet. I just literally did the go-pear installation in command prompt and thats it.

Answer (score 2):

The path separator for windows is `;` not `:` so

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/capeadmin/includes");
```

should change to

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ';'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/capeadmin/includes");
```

or better yet

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') .PATH_SEPARATOR. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/capeadmin/includes");
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! The error still persists however.

Comment: Make sure the php.ini you are changing is the one in the apache/bin directory in your wamp install.... the other one is for php cli scripts

Comment: I just noticed that the way he has it configured, the guy created his own DB.php file that does not come with PEAR-DB. I've emailed with this issue. This question will remain open

Comment: Thats a screen shot with apache/bin. its the same as the bin/php one.